# PEP234 iter,unexpected screen output

Tags: python, iterator

My code

```
import sys

f=open('iter.txt')
for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(20), ''):  
   n = sys.stdout.write(chunk)
   print(n)
```

Screen

```
Iteration is one of 20
Python’s strongest f20
eatures. At a high l20
evel, you might simp20
ly view
iteration as20
 a way to process it20
ems in a sequence. H20
owever, there is so 20
much more that
is po20
ssible, such as crea20
ting your own iterat20
or objects,
12
```

I expected chunk to be printed without this numerical value.How it comes that it appears?
I found this

```
iter(callable, sentinel)
This form creates an iterator out of any callable, and will stop when an exception is raised or the sentinel value is returned by the callable.
```

What is sentinel value?

Comment: Explicitly does `print(n)` - Wonders why it gets done.

Comment: I am using Python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.stdout.write` does the same as `print` except it does not add newline at the end. So if you want to remove numerical value remove `print(n)`.